# Of a "something", Why does "Of" can be used here and how to use it?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

"Most of the articles in the magazine are of a didactic nature."

There is a "Of" put before "a didactic nature"

Why does "Of" can be used here, and how to apply this sctuture to other sentence?

Comment: _Of_ is the default preposition used to link two nouns together, when one is felt to be needed. It can indicate possession, partitive, or some other property; or it can be governed by a particular noun, or a particular nominalization. For instance, _the shooting of the hunters_ can mean either that the hunters shot, or that they were shot. But _the shooting of the hunters by the soldiers_ is unambiguous, because grammar: when nominalizing a transitive clause like _the soldiers shot the hunters_, the subject takes _by_ and the object takes _of_, no matter what.

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition #10 in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of) gives this:

> 10 — used as a function word to indicate a characteristic or distinctive quality or possession: *a woman of courage*

So *of* can be used to describe the attributes of a person, similar to how it can be used to describe the attributes or components of an object - "heart of gold", "nerves of steel", etc.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> *Of* is the default preposition used to link two nouns together, when one is felt to be needed. It can indicate possession, partitive, or some other property; or it can be governed by a particular noun, or a particular nominalization. For instance, *the shooting of the hunters* can mean either that the hunters shot, or that they were shot. But *the shooting of the hunters by the soldiers* is unambiguous, because grammar: when nominalizing a transitive clause like *the soldiers shot the hunters*, the subject takes *by* and the object takes *of*, no matter what.

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question. Never considered it before so my answer will be partial, Others will probably add to it usefully.

The construction is common. *... are of a didactic nature* = *... have a didactic nature*.  Another example is *He is of a persuasive manner* = *he has a persuasive manner*.

There is also *I am of a mind to retire* = "I have a mind (or thought, notion, inclination) to retire" => *I am thinking of retiring*

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful.